# Maven Dependencies location - Java and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I moved to location of my java project from the place "a" to the place "b" of my computer. I changed all that was needed to be changed in Eclipse (because he need to know that my project is in place "b").

But the Maven Dependencies are still in place "a". Indeed, if i check that in Eclipse, my .java files (project) is in "/b/" but my .jar files (maven dependencies) are in "/a/".

I think it's a little button, like "Maven Update" or "Maven Install" but I already tried those two methods and the Maven Dependencies are still in the "a" location :/  .

I work in an entreprise and they have maybe 50/70 Maven Dependencies. I can't update one by one if it exists!

Thank you,
Clément.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your user's main directory there is `.m2` directory - you need to change line

```
    <localRepository>C:/Users/TheUser/.m2/forExample</localRepository>
```

inside `settings.xml` file to change the location of Maven's dependencies

Comment: This should work but I don't have acces to this file. I'm trying to re-launch a Maven Install but it's going to take something like 3-4 hours...